# Line graph using the COL parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

New to using seaborn, and would like to specify a simple and pretty(why im using seaborn) line graph.

Particularly I'm using Seaborn because it is my understanding that you can supply a column name to the seaborn col= parameter and it will create a graph for each unique value in that column.

[seaborn documentation](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid)

month_name contains month names such as Jan, Feb, Mar but I get the error:

```
"Could not convert OctoberJuneJulyAugustSeptember to numeric"
```

My code to plot a graph for each of the occurances of month_name i.e. Jan, Feb, etc

where person_name is on X axis, and Revenue they earned Y axis. Therefore since there are thwelve months I expect that the below generate a 12 graph grid (6x6).

```
sns.lmplot("person_name", "revenue", df, col="month_date", palette="Set1", fit_reg=False);
```

**Update**

The error is now: **ValueError: First argument must be a sequence** I get 5 blank graphs in a row from left to right with nothing in them. I assume first Argument refers to the X varaible --> "person name"? but how does one make the column (person_name) into a sequence?

[image]

Comment: Please add the full traceback so that it's more clear where the error is getting raised from. It would also be helpful to show the output of `df.head()` to get a better sense of what the data look like.

Comment: Also `lmplot` should be used when both the x and y variables are quantitative. `person_name` sounds categorical, perhaps you are looking for [`factorplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical_linear_models.html)?

Comment: mwaskom, yes I was just looking for any plot that will plot either category or number on the Y axis and dates i.e. 2014-11-30 (or text in the case of month_names; june, july etc) on the X axis.

Comment: mwaskom, I've added an example of the dataset with person name, month date, month name and revenue.

Comment: Are you able to up a copy pastable example that produces the error?